# bootstrap navigationbar links doesnt show 100% background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

So, I made a navigation bar with Bootstrap. 
This is what it looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It8r6.png).

The background color of the links are not `100%` height.

I want them to be like this:

[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9tl8.jpg)

I am new in web developing, so help would really be appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom" >
            <div class="container-fluid" >
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#" > <img class="img-responsive2" src="images/logo.jpg" > </a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </nav>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.navbar-custom
  {
    background-color:white;
    border:none;
    color:black;
    padding-right:5em;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    margin-bottom:0px !important;
    height:100%
    }
   .navbar-custom .navbar-nav 
   {
    padding-top:2.5em;
    padding-bottom:2.5em;
    height:100%;

    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .active 
     {
     background-color: #37B4FD;
      }
      .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
       background-color: green;
       }
        .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:visited
       {
       color:black;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the padding on the `.navbar-nav` class while you put background color effect on `.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .active`. What I recommend is to put the padding on the same element:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {
    padding-top:2.5em; 
    padding-bottom:2.5em; 
    height:100%;
}
```

Find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/j4fvzpew/)
Increase the size of "Result" panel to see the actual results

Comment: @ManveerSingh: Apparently, "navbar-nav" is inside of another div (i.e., "container-fluid") which is not 100% in height. I would recommend to add this snippet:
`.navbar-custom .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}`

Comment: @ManveerSingh: Use "Inspect Element" tool in Chrome or Mozilla Firefox to check out the margin and padding of elements containing "navbar", "container-fluid", and "navbar-nav" classes. There should be some margins which does not allow the 100% height. "Inspect element" is available at the right click on the page.

Comment: @zeropoint Padding makes the element 100% in height however. But there are no margins.

Comment: @ManveerSingh: found the issue. You have the padding on ".navbar-nav" class while you put background color effect on `.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .active`. What I recommend is to put the padding on the same element:
`.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {padding-top:2.5em;
    padding-bottom:2.5em;
    height:100%;}`
Find a working example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/j4fvzpew/)
increase the size of "Result" panel to see the actual results